# If $v+U=x+W$, with $U, W$ subspaces of $V$ then $0+U=x-v+W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x,v \in V$, with $U, W$ subspaces of $V$. If we have the following equality for affine spaces $v+U=x+W$, then do we have $0+U=x-v+W$?

I would say so, since we have $\forall_{u}\exists_w v+u=x+w$, which implies that $\forall_{u}\exists_w 0+u=x-v+w$, i.e. $0+U\subseteq x-v+W$, and similarly we could have derived $\forall_{w}\exists_u 0+u=x-v+w$, i.e. $0+U\supseteq x-v+W$, giving us the equality $0+U=x-v+W$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but normally you would write $U$ instead of $0 + U$. It even follows $x-v \in W$ (since you can put u=0) and hence $U=W$. More geometricly: If two affine subspaces are the same, then their translation spaces are the same (hence U=W).

Comment: @ctst That's where I was trying to reach... thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $v+U=x+W$; in particular, $x\in v+U$, so $x-v\in U$. Then
$$
v+U=v+(x-v)+U=x+U
$$
and from $x+U=x+W$ we deduce $U=W$, therefore $v+U=v+W=x+W=x+U$. The equality $0+U=x-v+W$ is now obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the help. +1 

Actually, I deduce what's in the op to reach that $U=W$

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. $x+U=x+W$ gives $-x+x+U=-x+x+W$.